# Error parsing Datetime format

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse two string values into DateTime.

```
DateTime processStartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(currentDateTime.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " " + "00:00", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);

DateTime processEndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(currentDateTime.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " " + "13:00", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

The first statement works fine, but the second statement fails with exception-

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe something about 24h / 12am-12pm format ? I mean, if the system use a.m / p.m system, 13 is not valid.

Comment: Check this [custom date & time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), it is clearly use `HH` for 24-hour format (`hh` is 12-hour one).

Comment: Not sure why the down vote

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `HH:mm` instead of `hh:mm` for 24h format

[The "hh" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#hhSpecifier):

> represents the hour as a number **from 01 through 12**; that is, the hour
>   is represented by a **12-hour clock** that counts the whole hours since
>   midnight or noon.

[The "HH" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-hh-custom-format-specifier):

> The "HH" custom format specifier (plus any number of additional "H"
>   specifiers) represents the hour as a number **from 00 through 23**; that
>   is, the hour is represented by a zero-based **24-hour clock** that counts
>   the hours since midnight. A single-digit hour is formatted with a
>   leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really converting a DateTime object to a string and then convert it back to a DateTime? Otherwise you could just write:

```
  var startTime = currentDateTime.Date;
  var endTime = currentDateTime.Date.AddHours(13);
```